# How do I split a large text file into about even size pieces without truncating a record?

Tags: perl, unix

I have a large text file (around 10 GB) which contains number of stories. Each story starts with the marker `$$`. Below is a sample of the file:

```
$$
AA This is story 1
BB 345

$$

AA This is story 2
BB 456
```

I want to split this file into pieces of around 250 MB size. But none of the stories should be divided into two different files.

Can anyone help me with the Unix or Perl code for this?

Answer (score 5):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

$/ = "\$\$\n";
my $targetsize = 250*1024*1024;
my $fileprefix = 'chunk';
my $outfile = 0;
my $outfh;
my $outsize = 0;
while (my $story = <>) {
    chomp($story);
    next unless $story; # disregard initial empty chunk
    $story = "$/$story";

    # no file open yet, or this story takes us farther from the target size
    if ( ! $outfile || abs($outsize - $targetsize) < abs($outsize + length($story) - $targetsize) ) {
        ++$outfile;
        open $outfh, '>', "$fileprefix$outfile";
        $outsize = 0;
    }

    $outsize += length($story);
    print $outfh $story;
}
```

Comment: I have not tested this code yet, but do you think, reading huge file of size 10 GB is feasible here? Wouldnt program throw an error saying 'system out of memory'?

Comment: Thanks,was just curious to know what is the use of autodie here? I commented the line as it was not installed at my system but now program is writing whole input file in chunk1..

Comment: @Man: autodie just makes the program die if an open fails, so that there's no need to have code to explicitly check if it fails; commenting it out shouldn't make a problem.  Is the whole input file more than 250Mb?  Is the separator between stories something other than exactly two dollar signs followed by a newline?

Comment: thanks for explaning. I think, record separater is the issue. When i do cat -vet test.txt | more, I get something like- $$^M$ story1 $$^M$ story2....

Answer (score 1):

[csplit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/csplit.1.asp) is what you want. It does the same as `split` but based on a pattern.

Alternative in C++ (not tested):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void new_output_file(boost::shared_ptr<std::ofstream> &out, const char *prefix)
{
    static int i = 0;
    std::ostringstream filename;
    filename << prefix << "_" << i++;
    out.reset(new std::ofstream(filename));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    int i = 0;
    long size = 0;
    const long max_size = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
    std::string line;
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ofstream> out(NULL);
    new_output_file(out, argv[2]);
    while(in.good())
    {
        std::getline(in,line);
        size += line.length() + 1 /* line termination char */;
        if(size >= max_size && line.length() && line[0] == '$' && line[1] == '$')
        {
            new_output_file(out, argv[2]);
            size = line.length() + 1;
        }
        out << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to meet the question at all.

Comment: Sure it does. You can supply a regular expression as your splitting criterion. If the questioner sets it to /\$\$/ then `csplit` should do what they want.

Comment: @CanSplice: but the goal isn't to split on the regular expression, it's to split about every 250Mb without breaking up \$\$\n separated chunks.  csplit doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the code but unfortunetly, it is throwing some compile time error. I am good to compile the cpp codes but not to debug it [:P] . Can you please check it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code of [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853625/2932052) and found it working. Please suggest if you think, you can modify this to make it better.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $targetsize = 50*1024*1024;
my $fileprefix = 'chunk';
my $outfile = 0;
my $outsize = 0;
my $outfh;
my $temp='';
while (my $line = <>)  {
  chomp($line);
  next unless $line;
  # discard initial empty chunk  
  if($line =~ /^\$\$$/ || $outfile == 0){
        $outsize += length($temp);
        if ( $outfile == 0 || ($outsize - $targetsize) > 0)  { 
              ++$outfile; 
              if($outfh) {close($outfh);}
              open $outfh, '>', "$fileprefix$outfile"; 
              $outsize = 0;
        }
        $temp='';
    }
  $temp = $temp.$line;
  print $outfh "$line\n";  
}
```

Comment: open automatically does a close first if the filehandle is open, but the explicit close doesn't hurt.  you are only using $temp for its length; you could just add to $outsize for each line instead.  you are removing empty lines inside of stories - is that intentional?  the lengths you are adding up don't include newlines, so will be slightly off; you could get rid of the chomp and the \n in the print and say next if $line eq "\n" instead.